# Check if a given date is the last day of the month

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a given date `d`:

```
d:2019.02.20
```

How to write a function `f` such that `f` is `True` if `d` is the last day of the month, `False` otherwise?

Example:

```
f[d]             / Should return 0b
f[2019.02.28]    / Should return 1b
f[2019.01.31]    / Should return 1b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the month part of the date with `mm$dt, or "m"$dt. See: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/7_Transforming_Data/#723-casts-that-narrow

Then just compare with your input date **+1** (which will add one day):

```
q)f:{(`mm$x) <> `mm$x+1}

q)f[2019.02.28 2020.02.28 2019.03.04 2019.03.31]
1001b
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to a month, add 1 to get next month, cast back to a date (which will give first day of month), subtract one and compare to input:

```
q){x=-1+"d"$1+"m"$x}[2019.02.28 2020.02.28 2019.03.04 2019.03.31]                                                                                    
1001b
```